# Unable to change brightness of screen

Tags: ios, objective-c

As I have to create a PDF reader with feature screen brightness low & high so I need to use the below code to change brightness but unfortunately it's not working in my case.

**Here is the code to change brightness:**

```
[[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness:slider.value];
```

Anything else I want to implement other than the above code?

**Slider value change event code:**

```
- (IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)sender {
    //Chnage Brighness based on slider value.
    [[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness:sender.value];
}
```

Please guide me as the above code is not working and not changing screen brightness at all.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10348421/unable-to-reset-brightness-on-application-exit-ios

Comment: What kind of values are you setting?

Comment: @ElTomato I am setting vale between 0.0 to 1.0.

Comment: @Amanpreet no its not related to any background foreground app brightness just i am setting brightness in active app.

Comment: NSLog slider.value and tell us the results...

Answer (score 0):

Code is working fine.

```
- (IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)sender {
   // reflecting slider value 
   [[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness:sender.value];
}
```

Check the event you connected with slider is `valueChanged` not anything else and the min and max value should be `0 to 1`.

If you testing this using simulator it wont work use apple device.

Comment: try setting up the slider value its 0 to 1 using storyboard and connect slider with valueChanged event, further you need to show some more code and screenshots.